# How to upload file into docker volume

Tags: docker

I am facing the problem of how to save photos on the server side. Well, my application is on the docker and from what I've read, it's best to use docker volume. The problem is that I do not know how to send Base64 images on the docker volume. When creating the volume, I am using docker-compose.yml.

Comment: A volume is exposed as a directory in your container. You just save files to it like you would to any other directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using docker compose you can map volume like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  cluster:
    image: <image-name> 
    volumes:
        - ./path/to/imagefile64:/path/in/container/imagefile64 # This is a file containing image content in base 64
```

or you can simply do the same thing by bind mounting the image then converting it to base64 inside the container

Comment: `./path/to/imagefile64` is the path in my host machine or in project structure?

Comment: It is the path to the image file inside your host machine starting from the current directory with `./relative/path:/path/inside/container` or starting from the base directory like `/C/Users/piotror/absolute/path:/path/inside/container`